# using two recordset vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Cells.Clear
Dim oConn1 As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs1 As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset
Set oConn1 = New ADODB.Connection
oConn1.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=" & Contraseña.Text & ";Persist Security Info=True;User ID= " & Usuario.Text & "; Initial Catalog =" & bases.Text & ";Data Source= SERVER\BD;"
oConn1.ConnectionTimeout = 200
oConn1.Open

Set rs1 = New ADODB.Recordset
rs1.ActiveConnection = oConn1

rs1.Source = "DECLARE @id INT" & _
             "SET @id = @@spid" & _
             "INSERT CLIENTES_SALDOS_E (PROCESO_ID, CODIGO_DE_CLIENTE)" & _
             "SELECT @id, CODIGO_DE_CLIENTE" & _
             "FROM CLIENTES" & _
             "WHERE CLIENTES.CODIGO_DE_CLIENTE BETWEEN '" & EXTRA(Ncuenta) & "' AND '" & EXTRA(Ncuenta2) & "'" & _
             "EXECUTE sp_Reconstruccion_saldo_doctos "", '" & EXTRA(Fechacorte) & "', @id"

 Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset
 rs2.ActiveConnection = oConn1


 rs2.Source = "SELECT P.NOMBRE_DEPARTAMENTO,M.NOMBRE_MUNICIPIO,R.NOMBRE_TERRITORIO,V.NOMBRE_VENDEDOR,C.CODIGO_DE_CONDICION,E.CODIGO_DE_CLIENTE,C.NOMBRE_CLIENTE,D.CODIGO_MOVIMIENTO," & _
            "D.SERIE_DEL_DOCUMENTO,D.NUMERO_DOCUMENTO,(ME.MONTO_TOTAL * ME.CAMBIO_MONEDA_LOCAL) AS MONTO_MONEDA_LOCAL,D.SALDO_MONEDA_LOCAL,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),D.FECHA_DOCUMENTO,103) AS FECHA_DOCUMENTO," & _
            "CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),D.FECHA_VENCIMIENTO,103) AS FECHA_VENCIMIENTO,D.DIAS_DE_ANTIGUEDAD," & _
            "CASE WHEN D.DIAS_DE_ANTIGUEDAD =0 THEN D.SALDO_MONEDA_LOCAL  ELSE 0 END AS 'NO VENCIDO'," & _
            "CASE WHEN D.DIAS_DE_ANTIGUEDAD >=1  AND D.DIAS_DE_ANTIGUEDAD <=15 THEN D.SALDO_MONEDA_LOCAL ELSE 0 END AS 'DE 1 A 15 DIAS'," & _
            "CASE WHEN D.DIAS_DE_ANTIGUEDAD >=16 AND D.DIAS_DE_ANTIGUEDAD <=30 THEN D.SALDO_MONEDA_LOCAL ELSE 0 END AS 'DE 16 A 30 DIAS'," & _
            "CASE WHEN D.DIAS_DE_ANTIGUEDAD >=31 AND D.DIAS_DE_ANTIGUEDAD <=60 THEN D.SALDO_MONEDA_LOCAL ELSE 0 END AS 'DE 31 A 60 DIAS'," & _
            "CASE WHEN D.DIAS_DE_ANTIGUEDAD >=61 AND D.DIAS_DE_ANTIGUEDAD <=90 THEN D.SALDO_MONEDA_LOCAL ELSE 0 END AS 'DE 61 A 90 DIAS'," & _
            "CASE WHEN D.DIAS_DE_ANTIGUEDAD >=91 AND D.DIAS_DE_ANTIGUEDAD <=9999 THEN D.SALDO_MONEDA_LOCAL ELSE 0 END AS 'DE 91 A 9999 DIAS'" & _
            "FROM CLIENTES C" & _
            "INNER JOIN CLIENTES_SALDOS_E E ON E.CODIGO_DE_CLIENTE = C.CODIGO_DE_CLIENTE" & _
            "INNER JOIN CLIENTES_SALDOS_D D ON D.CODIGO_DE_CLIENTE = E.CODIGO_DE_CLIENTE AND D.PROCESO_ID = E.PROCESO_ID" & _
            "INNER JOIN MOVIMIENTOS_TIPO T  ON T.CODIGO_MOVIMIENTO = D.CODIGO_MOVIMIENTO" & _
            "INNER JOIN DEPARTAMENTOS P     ON C.CODIGO_DE_PAIS    = P.CODIGO_DE_PAIS    AND C.CODIGO_DEPARTAMENTO = P.CODIGO_DEPARTAMENTO" & _
            "INNER JOIN MUNICIPIOS M        ON C.CODIGO_DE_PAIS    = M.CODIGO_DE_PAIS    AND C.CODIGO_DEPARTAMENTO = M.CODIGO_DEPARTAMENTO AND C.CODIGO_MUNICIPIO = M.CODIGO_MUNICIPIO" & _
            "INNER JOIN TERRITORIOS R       ON C.CODIGO_TERRITORIO = R.CODIGO_TERRITORIO" & _
            "LEFT JOIN CLIENTE_VENDEDOR CV  ON C.CODIGO_DE_CLIENTE = CV.CODIGO_DE_CLIENTE" & _
            "LEFT JOIN VENDEDORES V         ON CV.CODIGO_VENDEDOR = V.CODIGO_VENDEDOR" & _
            "INNER JOIN MOVIMIENTO_ENC ME   ON D.SERIE_DEL_DOCUMENTO = ME.SERIE_DEL_DOCUMENTO AND D.NUMERO_DOCUMENTO = ME.NUMERO_DOCUMENTO AND D.CODIGO_MOVIMIENTO = ME.CODIGO_MOVIMIENTO" & _
            "WHERE E.PROCESO_ID = @id AND T.TIPO_TRANSACCION = 'S' AND D.ID_EMPRESA = 'GN' AND D.ID_SUCURSAL = '01' AND D.ID_CENTRO_OPERATIVO = '001' AND D.SALDO_MONEDA_LOCAL > 0" & _
            "DELETE CLIENTES_SALDOS_E WHERE  PROCESO_ID = @id" & _
            "DELETE CLIENTES_SALDOS_D WHERE  PROCESO_ID = @id"


rs2.Open
encabezados
Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs2
'a = rs1.Fields.Count
rs1.Close
rs2.Close
oConn1.Close
MsgBox ("Reporte Generado")
Set rs1 = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing
Set oConn1 = Nothing

End If
End Sub
```

When i run this code, give me a incorrect syntax near 'E' error, I divided the code in two recordset because in only one give me the error: there is to many continuation of lines, but now i have incorrect syntax error.
I guess the error is because in the where clause of the recordset 2, makes reference to the variable declared on the recordset 1, and i dont know how tell the query to the E.PROCESO_ID is in the recordset 1.

How can i fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Paste the entire SQL statement into a worksheet cell and read it from there.  Then you don't have to worry about the concatenation and your code will be much simpler.

Comment: ... I meant to add that you can include tokens in the SQL which can be replaced e.g. :  `SQL = Replace(SQL, "{NCUENTA}", EXTRA(Ncuenta))`

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is the problem is missing spaces here. Right now your statement reads

```
FROM CLIENTES CINNER JOIN CLIENTES_SALDOS
```

but it should read

```
FROM CLIENTES C INNER JOIN CLIENTES_SALDOS
```

So add a space in front of every `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks Waka, but the same result after adding the space you mentioned.

Comment: @CarlosGaleano: Strange. Is it the exact same error? Is it possbile for you to create a [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some sample data?

Comment: you mean the result of the sql code only? this code works perfectly if you run the code in the management studio, the problem is when you split the code in two recordsets because in one recordset give the error there is too many continues lines.

Comment: @CarlosGaleano: No, I meant creating both queries on the linked site adding some sample data so we have some return values if the query is fixed. Since the error message states "syntax error" there has to be something wrong with the query itself. Possibly due to the string concatenation.

Comment: thanks for your help, i fixed the syntax error, there was some spaces between the end of the line and the " & _ , that was causing the problem.  but now i have another problema, when execute the recordset 2 give the error that i have to declare the @id variable, i have to use the variable declared on the recordset 1, i dont know how to do that. thanks.

Comment: I guess your second problem should be asked in a second question. Also, I really don't know, sorry. :(